# How do we write a function F(x) into F(x,t) ??

Tags: functions

Please see the link below:

[Plane wave expansion](http://www.phys.ubbcluj.ro/~emil.vinteler/nanofotonica/PWM/pwmmanual_Guo.pdf)

My question is if you notice equation (13) in the manual is written the function f(G) as F(G,lambda) using a transverse property?? My question is how is that possible???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the text below, you see that $h(G_i)$ is a vector, and $h(G_i, \lambda)$ denotes its component in the $\lambda$ direction, so that

$$h(G_i) = h(G_i, \lambda_1) e_{\lambda_1} + \cdots + h(G_i, \lambda_n) e_{\lambda_n},$$

where $\{e_{\lambda_1}, \ldots, e_{\lambda_n}\}$ is a basis.

Personally I think the notation is confusing and terrible, but getting engineers to write clearly is a lost cause.

(Disclaimer: I didn't read anything other than the one equation and the sentence below it.)

Comment: A cause clearly do engineers getting is lost say to why write you?

Comment: Hahaha...very funny!! But ironically quite true!!!

Comment: Can any of you provide my a pdf explaining these sort of things....It would of great help for me!!

Comment: Well the notation is the author's own and probably doesn't show up anywhere else.  If you're talking about breaking a vector into a sum of its components, that's basic linear algebra and there's probably a whole shelf on that at your library.